Critical exponents of ising model at $d=4$
Many references state that the critical exponents of the Ising model in $d=4$ follow mean-field values. Indeed, Sokal (1979) and Aizenman (1986) have shown that exponents such as $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ conform to mean-field theory. However, I could not find any literature addressing whether the values of $\nu$ and $\eta$ follow mean-field theory or whether hyperscaling holds in $d=4$. Could you provide any rigorous results that discuss these aspects?

Note that as Yvan article says, all(most all) variables will not be following power law at the upper critical dimension (4d for ising). They will have logarithmic (sometimes called "marginal" due to the fact that the non-linear term is marginal in the RG sense) corrections such as $\sim(T - T_c)^\beta \log(T - T_c)^{\beta'}$. See for example: https://www.lptmc.jussieu.fr/files/chap_rg.pdf or the book: Critical Dynamics: A Field Theory Approach to Equilibrium and Non-Equilibrium Scaling Behavior for an easy read concerning this

Hi. Please read this, and consider to either accept an answer if it solved your issue or clarify if something is missing or not clear, by e.g. leaving a comment. This is also important for all other questions. Else the questions unnecessarily appear as "unanswered". You are of course not obliged to accept any answer at all, but keep in mind how this site works.

The proof that $\eta=0$ and $\nu=1/2$ in dimension 4 (and higher) can be found in this very recent article by Duminil-Copin and Panis.

This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.
